# Possible struts-portlet 2.3.3 bug? Action class not at the top of the value stack

Tags: struts2, portlet, ognl

I'm in the process of migrating a struts 2.2.3.1 portlet application (jsr168) to the new version, 2.3.3. For the most part everything still works the same, but there was one obvious problem.

I'm using a package.properties resource bundle for things like titles and labels in my jsp's. When I first hit an action, the messages are retrieved from the resource bundle and displayed as expected. When I make a second request to an action though, the message keys are displayed, which typically means the resource was not found.

(The main difference between the first time hitting an action and any subsequent request seems to be that on the first request ONLY the event portlet phase is processed, and not the render portlet phase. Any follow up requests both phases are used.)

It took me quite a while to figure out what is going on, but here is roughly what's happening:

I started out by stepping through **org.apache.struts2.components.Text**. This class is used when a struts text tag is encountered in a jsp.

The *end()* method uses the static *getText()* method from the **TextProviderHelper**. This is where I found the root of the problem:

```
    for (Object o : stack.getRoot()) {
        if (o instanceof TextProvider) {
            tp = (TextProvider) o;
            msg = tp.getText(key, null, args, stack);

            break;
        }
    }
```

The above code iterates through the value stack until it finds a **TextProvider**. Because **ActionSupport** implements **TextProvider**, and because struts tries to put the action at or near the top of the stack, the action is usually the provider.

Here's the objects in the value stack at different times for both versions:

## Version 2.2.3.1

### First request value stack

- -->*TestPortletAction*
- DefaultTextProvider

### Second request value stack

- -->*TestPortletAction*
- DefaultTextProvider
- DirectRenderFromEventAction
- DefaultTextProvider

## Version 2.3.3

### First request value stack

- -->*TestPortletAction*
- DefaultTextProvider

### Second request value stack

- DirectRenderFromEventAction
- DefaultTextProvider
- -->*TestPortletAction*
- DefaultTextProvider

So, for some reason, in the new version the action class is not at the top of the stack after the render phase is processed. This means that the **TextProviderHelper** uses the **DefaultTextProvider**, which does try to locate the resource bundle... but is never successful in doing so.

I did some investigation into how that **DefaultTextProvider** gets pushed into the stack:

**Jsr168Dispatcher**.*serviceAction*() makes the call to the **ActionProxyFactory** to create the action proxy. Just before returning the proxy a call is made to *prepare*(), which in turn makes a call to the **DefaultActionInvocation**'s *init* method. The init calls *createContextMap*() which creates the stack

```
stack = valueStackFactory.createValueStack();
```

The constructor used:

```
protected OgnlValueStack(XWorkConverter xworkConverter, CompoundRootAccessor accessor, TextProvider prov, boolean allowStaticAccess) {
    setRoot(xworkConverter, accessor, new CompoundRoot(), allowStaticAccess);
    push(prov);
}
```

Aaaaaand that's about as far as I have got on the problem so far. The questions that remain are:

1. How and where does the second **DefaultTextProvider** get pushed onto the stack? (And is there a real reason to have two of them?)
2. How and where does the **DirectRenderFromEventAction** get pushed onto the stack?
3. What change in the new version is causing this?
4. Is this a bug or intended behavior?

A possible solution (that does fix it) is to explicitly call the action's *getText* method using ognl, but I don't see this as ideal, and it does mean changing a bunch of jsp files.

```
<s:property value = "%{getText('some.key')}"/>
```

A sample project that demonstrates the problem can be found here (It's a maven project):

http://new-value-stack-order.googlecode.com/svn

I'm using **tomcat 6.0.25** with **pluto 1.1.7** as my development environment.

Comment: Just found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2387

Comment: This is probably something best-asked on the S2 user mailing list; the portlet guy is a regular. I don't know enough about portlets to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The answer lies in the **PortletStateInterceptor**

**2.2.3.1**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void restoreStack(ActionInvocation invocation) {
    RenderRequest request = (RenderRequest) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(REQUEST);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getParameter(EVENT_ACTION))) {
        if(!isProperPrg(invocation)) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Restoring value stack from event phase");
            ValueStack oldStack = (ValueStack) invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get(
            STACK_FROM_EVENT_PHASE);
            if (oldStack != null) {
                CompoundRoot oldRoot = oldStack.getRoot();
                ValueStack currentStack = invocation.getStack();
                CompoundRoot root = currentStack.getRoot();
                root.addAll(0, oldRoot);
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Restored stack");
            }
        }
        else {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Won't restore stack from event phase since it's a proper PRG request");
        }
    }
}
```

**2.3.3**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void restoreStack(ActionInvocation invocation) {
    RenderRequest request = (RenderRequest) invocation.getInvocationContext().get(REQUEST);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getParameter(EVENT_ACTION))) {
        if(!isProperPrg(invocation)) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Restoring value stack from event phase");
            ValueStack oldStack = (ValueStack) invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get(
            STACK_FROM_EVENT_PHASE);
            if (oldStack != null) {
                CompoundRoot oldRoot = oldStack.getRoot();
                ValueStack currentStack = invocation.getStack();
                CompoundRoot root = currentStack.getRoot();
                root.addAll(oldRoot);
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Restored stack");
            }
        }
        else {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Won't restore stack from event phase since it's a proper PRG request");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the root.addAll(). In the old version it adds the old stack to the beginning of the current stack. In the new version it adds it to the end.

This was actually an old bug fixed in 2.1.3. Creating a new issue in Jira.